# tail -f equivalent for MySQL logging database

Tags: mysql, logging

It was decided that we should move to using a (MySQL) database for our application logs (it is a Java app using the logback lib). I am hoping to find something like `tail -f` that I can use with a specific table in that database that will show me new rows as they are added (similar to how `tail -f` worked on log files).

Comment: I'm looking for this too. Clarification on the subject: Of course we can poll the database or binlog periodically to detect data changes. That is a no brainer. But is there someway one can `tail -f` the bin log, so to be **notifiied** when changes occur, that *avoids* periodic polling. The difficulty with polling is especially determing the polling interval. Too short and you're wasting resources. Too long and you introduce delay into the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on MySQL binary logging.  Then you can use the `mysqlbinlog` command to see all data-modifying statements.

Comment: can you show an example of how to do this in the language of your choice or with bash?

Comment: This does not `tail -f` (follow) the binlog to show rows "as they are added". It allows for a polling approach, but then we might as well use a periodic query.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think  some people understand the question (or I don't). You don't want to log the queries against the DB; rather a log from an application is going into a DB. If it were a file you could tail the log. How do you tail a table so that when a new row is added it is output?

It shouldn't be to hard to write a simple loop to handle this, assuming you have a unique field that monotonically increases over time (e.g., a sequence number).

```
current_pos = select max(seq) from table
while true
  new_pos = select max(seq) from table
  if new_pos > current_pos
    select * from table where seq > current_pos
    current_pos = new_pos
  endif
  sleep 1
endwhile
```

Comment: this is called polling and it's not that much fun :) but a good technique I suppose, if you must use polling.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that many of us don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by ["logging database"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22logging+database%22), which isn't a standard MySQL term.

Use the MySQL [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html), which logs each statement received from a client.

You can then set [log_output = TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output) in your my.cnf . The file will be written to $mysql_data_directory/general_log.CSV . You can `tail -f` this file to view queries in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use. Seems the simplest solution, though it's not very efficient:

`watch "mysql db_name -e '(SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY id ASC;'"`

Comment: `watch` does not `tail -f` (follow) the binlog to show rows "as they are added". It allows for a polling approach, but then we might as well use a periodic query.

Answer (score 2):

If you have binary logging enabled in MySQL, you can use this method from https://coderwall.com/p/0tmhla/tailing-mysql-binary-log to tail queries:

```
export D=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date="30 minutes ago"); watch "mysqlbinlog --start-datetime=\"$D\" /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.000001|tail"
```

It will watch the binary log and updates the output every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a hacky way by using `tail -f` on the database files in `/var/lib/mysql/database_name/table_name.MY*` and then running your query every time a line is read.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a timestamp field to any table you want to tail. That will allow you to get the desired results very easily with a simple query.

Comment: This does not `tail -f` (follow) the binlog to show rows "as they are added". It allows for a polling approach, but then we might as well use a periodic query.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to give this a go:

http://www.jetprofiler.com/blog/10/tail--f-table-with-myterm/#comments

It's old and hasn't been touched for 3 years - but I just tried it out and it works OK. Clone the BZR repo and read the README.

Comment: This polls the database "every second" and does not `tail -f` (follow) the binlog to show rows "as they are added". It allows for a polling approach, but then we might as well use a periodic query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java library that can do a "real" `tail -f` of the binlog:

[shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java: MySQL Binary Log connector](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java)

With `mysql-binlog-connector-java` you can actually *react* asynchronously to changes in the binlog *without* periodic polling.

It allows you to:

```java
BinaryLogClient client = new BinaryLogClient("hostname", 3306, "username", "password");
EventDeserializer eventDeserializer = new EventDeserializer();
...
client.setEventDeserializer(eventDeserializer);
client.registerEventListener(new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        ...
    }
});
client.connect();
```

Note that the data in `Event event` is not a super-handy as you've come to expect from your faviorite MySQL client, as the data is lower-level than that. See the link above for details.

Also, here is a [list of projects that will let you do replication from MySQL to Kafka](https://github.com/wushujames/mysql-cdc-projects/wiki) where I found `mysql-binlog-connector-java`. You can also find equivalents in at least go and python.